# geoChoroplethChart map with different fill opacity for the selected item

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, dc.js, crossfilter

I've implemented an [infographic / map](http://smenglish.github.io/dash_snow/) using [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) and [d3.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D3.js).

What I would like is to add the functionality of...

When a user clicks a particular entity, in my case a member country of the european union, the fill opacity of the selected state differentiates itself from the rest, i.e. becomes darker.

I found a nice example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/ewheeler/5354775), but the code there doesn't exactly specify where the part is that deals with selection of the state.

As you can see on [my map](http://smenglish.github.io/dash_snow/) nothing at all distinguishes a selected state on the map, I feel this is very disconcerting to users.

All of my code can be found [here](https://github.com/smenglish/dash_snow).

This is the part most closely related to the map itself:

```
        //This is the data for the Map
    d3.json("data/europe.json", function (error, eu) { 

        console.log('map', eu)
        usChart
        .width(590)
        .height(500)
        .projection(projection
                    .scale((1200 + 1) / 2 )
                    .translate([660 / 4, 3360 / 4])
                    .precision(.1)
                    )
                .dimension(countries)
                .group(countriesJobsdSum)

                    .filterHandler(function(dimension, filter){     
    dimension.filter(function(d) {return usChart.filter() != null ? d.indexOf
    (usChart.filter()) >= 0 : true;}); // perform filtering
    return filter; // return the actual filter value
 })

                .colors(d3.scale.quantize().range(
                    ["#8c857d", "#d982ab", "#d9525e", "#a63f52", "#8c6976", "#55b1b1", "#637e9e"])
                )
                .colorDomain([0, 200])
                .colorCalculator(function (d) { return d ? usChart.colors()(d) : '#ccc'; })
                .overlayGeoJson(eu.features, "countries", function (d) {
                    return d.properties.name;
                    //return d.properties.Country;
                })
                .transitionDuration(0)
                .title(function (d) {
                    return "Country: " + d.key + "\nNumber of Jobs: " + numberFormat(d.value ? d.value : 0) ;
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is that dc.js already adds classes to target selected and deselected elements. You just need to add css to style those elements however you want them.

You could do something like

```
g.deselected path {
    fill: gray;
}
```

to remove color from the deselected regions.

Or you could

```
g.selected path {
    stroke: yellow;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

to highlight the region(s) that is/are selected.

Comment: can I do other things by referencing this selected element, for instance, I want center my map around the selected element, is that possible?

Comment: You can get the selected elements using the selector either with jquery or d3. You'll have to do some calculation once you get them...it's not built-in or anything. I'll keep my eye out for a follow up question.There can be more than one element selected, and that will complicate things a little bit--don't forget to code for that scenario.

Comment: Yes. You might also want to get the ability to zoom and pan working independently. Here is a good example of that: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7ec977c95910dd026812

Comment: That's true, but the thing with those examples is- I've found- that they don't conform so inutitively to the `dc.geoChoroplethChart` construct.